# Integrate an IM chat server to existing Spring server

Tags: sql-server, xmpp, springframework, scale

I'm trying to integrate an openFire XMPP server to my current company Spring server but have two major questions I cannot find the answer to -

I'll start with my current architecture first - 
1. The xmpp server have a DB-server of it's own seperated from the Spring server DB, This is a dedicated machine to keep the users char history etc
2. The spring server have a DB of it's own where it keeps the user credentials (md5 encrypted) and also client applications data
3. The spring server is dedicated to serve HTTP requests (a dedicated REST server)

All in all I have 2 DB servers once chat server and one Rest server

Now for the questions - 
 1. Can I forbid registration to the xmpp server (i.e. whitelist the rest server ip and let it be the only one who can create users after a user registers on it)?
2.For security reasons the Rest server switch the session for a logged in user every 2 days the iOS and Android clients deal with session managment locally - How can I use those session with the XMPP server?
To clarify - I want the users to be able use the xmpp server only for chat purposes but only after they logged in to the application itself since the user session may expire the chat client will also have to re-authenticate against the REST server, how can I achieve this?
 3. Won't it create an overload on the REST server? (i.e. the Rest server will now have to handle client requests and also XMPP server requests)
4. What is the best architecture to achieve this kind of a system (chat server, db server for chat server, rest server, db server for rest server) so that the system can scale horizontally?

I searched google for an article or something related to describe the general architecture but couldn't find nothing relevant, since I'm  not "inveneting the wheel" here I would love to hear a good advice or be directed to an article that explains the How-To's

Thanks in advance.